# Pandas to time delta with only hours minutes and seconds

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

In my script i extract a excel that in one column called "Time" is dtype object, in that column there's a hour like so "14:00:00" i want to convert the column to_datetime but when i do this :

```
df['Time']=pandas.to_datetime(df['Time'],format='%H:%M:%S')
```

i adds the year month and day to it and i dont want that to happen and i also want to keep that column as a datetime so i can then subtract to another time and get the seconds.
How can i pass it to datetime with only the hours minutes and seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.time.html):

```
import pandas as pd

# sample
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['00:00:05', '00:00:10', '00:10:00']})

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time

print(type(df.Time[0]))
[out]:
<class 'datetime.time'>
```

For adding or subtracting `time`, you can do this:

```
pd.Timedelta(df.Time - t1).seconds / 3600.0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `timedelta`:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
```

---

To calculate minutes:

```
pd.to_timedelta(df.time).dt.seconds/60
```